# nginx works only for the file name "index.html"

Tags: nginx

I am trying to setup nginx to my web application which have multiple pages (ex: Login, register, sign-in, forget password etc)

I am aware of setting up the location / {} for these folders for redirection , but nginx is by default only considering index.html files if i have any files with other name for ex:test.html its not serving the file & throwing 404 error. not sure What to do

Below is my sample nginx file

```html
    server {
        listen      8085;
        server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location /login {
            root   html/login;
            try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/index.html;
        }
        location ~ ^/(images|javascript|js|css|flash|media|static)/  {
      root    html/login;
    }
```

Kindly let me know how can I achieve nginx to serve files with *.html as name other than index.html

Comment: could you please share your rules which you have written in your nginx file in your question, that will give us better understanding of question, thank you.

Comment: Can you please check now i have updated the code